# Laravel mail log dumping attachments

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I cant track down the event in the framework, which is logging mails sent (via mailgun api). It is dumping raw attachment data (in my case, pdf splurge) into the log - and I want to stop this!

I have found what looks like the the event and it being fired

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending.php`

But cant see where it actually does anything!

Is this possible to either disable logs? Or stop it logging attachment data

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `$message->attachData($data, $name, array $options = []);` instead of `$message->attach(...)`

Comment: Hi Maraboc, what will this change?

Comment: I think it will send the email with the attached data and without leaving a copy on server it that what you want?

Comment: I'm ok with the file left on the server, as it one that can be accessed via a web interface. It is the raw content of the file that is being dumped to the log which i have an issue with. Laravel itself is logging the sending of the mail, and dumping the contents to the log file - along with the raw binary(maybe not?) dump from the pdf - making a mess of the logs when im trying to read it

Comment: Hey @OnIIcE, did you happen to find the answer? I have the same problem too